# Beautiful Soup - getting value from tag definition

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

HTML Code:

```
<option data-formated='&lt;span class="price"&gt;AUD $100.08&lt;/span&gt;' data-qtyid="qty-219" value="1">
                                    Unit Price                              </option>
```

how do i get AUD $100.08 out of this?

Comment: `find('option')['data-formated']` and you should have string which you can slice/split/ect. to get only `AUD $100.08`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
find('option')['data-formated']
```

to get text `<span class="price">AUD $100.08</span>` and then you can slice/span()/etc. - ie `[20:-7]` - or you can use again `BeautifulSoup` to search in this HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''<option data-formated='&lt;span class="price"&gt;AUD $100.08&lt;/span&gt;' data-qtyid="qty-219" value="1">
                                    Unit Price                              </option>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('option')['data-formated'] 
print(item[20:-7])  # AUD $100.08 

soup = BeautifulSoup(item, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span').text)  # AUD $100.08
```